# Symfony2 Entities with CRUD

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, crud

I have two entities:

**File Company.php**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Company")
 */

class Company
{
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        protected $id;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
        protected $name;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
        protected $bulstat;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
        protected $city;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50) */
        protected $email;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50) */
        protected $contact_person;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50) */
        protected $telephone;
}
?>
```

**File Employer.php**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Employer")
 */

class Employer
{
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        protected $id;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
        protected $name;

        /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
        protected $position;

        /**
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company")
        * @ORM\JoinTable(name="employer2companies",
        *       joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="employer_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        *       inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
        *       )
        */

        private $companies;

        public function __construct() {
                $this->companies = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

}
?>
```

Everything seems correct:

```
php console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:
Generating entities for bundle "AppBundle"
  > backing up Company.php to Company.php~
  > generating AppBundle\Entity\Company
  > backing up Employer.php to Employer.php~
  > generating AppBundle\Entity\Employer

php console doctrine:schema:update --force:
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "5" queries were executed
```

After this, I'm generating CRUD for AppBundle:Company and AppBundle:Employer successfully!

I can successfully create a new company from the CRUD interface, but when I try to create a new Employer I get this error at http://xxxxx.com/admin/employer/new:

```
Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when thiserror occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

Here is the exception:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Company could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `__toString()` method to your class `AppBundle\Entity\Company`.

Best regards, Alexander

Comment: I just added:

      public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
        }
in Company.php,